# Force Postgres shift to uppercase rather than lowercase before sorting case insensitive?

Tags: postgresql, collation, uppercase

I try to migrate to postgres from pervasive. In pervasive there was something like 'upper.alt' - alternative collation. I don't really know how it works, but I have to make my new postgres database to behave like pervasive with this collation.

I use Postgres 9.2.4 and utf-8 encoding and `LC_COLLATE='Polish_Poland.1250'` .

Comment: A sort can't make a value appear or disappear. I assume that's just a mistake, so please edit your post and correct it. In the process please supply your PostgreSQL version from `select version()` and *explain in words* what the sorting rules you want are and what you have already tried. Since it's about collation, you might want to mention what locale your database is in too - see `\d+` in `psql`.

Comment: What's relevant is your **locale**, not so much your encoding. What do you get from `SHOW lc_collate;`

Comment: I am surprised that `upper()` would have an effect on the sort order with underscores (`_`) in Polish locale. I don't have it installed to test ...

Comment: I'm sorry. You are right. Function upper() does not change sort order.

Comment: Your sample is still wrong, `ABC_ZZZZZ` magically appears from nowhere. Is it supposed to go after `ABC_BBBBBB` in the first dataset? And what's the logic behind this sorting - explain in words what you want. It's clear that "sort underscores last" is part of it, but is that all? what about `"ABC-AAAAA"`, `"ABC AAAAAA"`, etc? And *why*? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and order with COLLATE "C". That would get what you want in your example. It has side effects though! Effectively everything is ordered according to the byte values of the encoded character.

```
WITH x(col) AS (
    VALUES
     ('ABC_AAAAA')
    ,('ABC_BBBBB')
    ,('ABC_ZZZZZ')
    ,('ABCAAAAA')
    ,('ABCBBBBB')
    ,('ABCZZZZZ')
    )
SELECT *
FROM   x
ORDER  BY col COLLATE "C"
```

This option to change the collation for individual expressions (as opposed to using a collation defined at creation time of the db) was introduced with Postgres 9.1.
[More about collation in the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COLLATE-EXPRS).

Comment: It's a real pity you can't add custom collations since Pg uses the built-in OS collation support. Being able to provide a custom collation function or array would be quite interesting. One of those things that might come if/when ICU support can ever be added.